# C child process runs its code twice

Tags: c, fork, sleep

Total C noob here, looking for some help with `fork()`. I'm not sure why its print the child process 2 code twice. I believe it has to do with the `sleep` call because it was working fine before.

### Output

```
Child Process 2
Process ID: 31973
Parent Process ID: 1

Child Process 1
Process ID: 31972
Parent Process ID: 1

Child Process 2
Process ID: 31974
Parent Process ID: 1
```

## C Code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE // required for cuserid to work

// includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void) {
    getP0Info();
    putenv("WHALE=7");
    forkProcesses();
    return 0;
}
// Prints an error message and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error; we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void forkProcesses() {

    pid_t child1_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
    if (child1_pid == 0) {
        printf("\nChild Process 1\n");
        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d\n", getppid());

        sleep(1);
        int whale = atoi(getenv("WHALE"));
        printf("C1: %d\n", whale);

    }

    pid_t child2_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
    if (child2_pid == 0) {
        printf("\nChild Process 2\n");
        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d\n", getppid());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because child process 1's execution continues even after the if-statement is over. You need to explicitly call `_exit()` or such to prevent this:

```
void forkProcesses() {

    pid_t child1_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
    if (child1_pid == 0) {
        printf("\nChild Process 1\n");
        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d\n", getppid());

        sleep(1);
        int whale = atoi(getenv("WHALE"));
        printf("C1: %d\n", whale);
        _exit(0);
    }

    pid_t child2_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
    if (child2_pid == 0) {
        printf("\nChild Process 2\n");
        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d\n", getppid());

    }
}
```

In theory, `return` or `exit` would also avoid running the rest of the code, but doing so is dangerous: if you exit the child process using `exit`, stdio buffers are flushed in the child and `atexit` handlers run, too.  If any data from before the fork remains in these buffers, it will then be printed twice.

This is avoided by terminating the fork with `_exit()`.

Comment: Is any reason why return wouldn't be enough? I had the same problem, but a little bit different where the forked child would call the code above it. The return didn't work, but when I tried ```_exit(0)``` it did the job.

Comment: @will Rule of thumb: you'll want to terminate the forked process using `_exit()` instead of `exit` so that neither stdio buffers are flushed twice nor are `atexit()` handlers run twice.  I'll adjust the answer to indicate that.